# "errorCode":40001,"message":"'message' is required"

Tags: sinch

After running the execute command from the quickstart page I get the following error:

> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
>   {"errorCode":40001,"message":"'message' is required","reference":"BA:1f96aea6-a1
>   ae-434c-aaf5-23ed7add6126_Qze9ELkQ0Uq79fIB+4XF0Q"}

Here is the execute command:

```
curl --user "application\1f96aea6-a1ae-434c-aaf5-23ed7add6126:698vdzO63EGqxBz1wFi4rg==" 
     --data '{"message":"hello world"}' 
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://messagingapi.sinch.com/v1/sms/+17203419809
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41092848/edit) and change `the quickstart page` into `[the quickstart page](URL of the quickstart page)` so we can follow along.

Comment: Works for me with postman